# wget for selected samples from ftp?

Tags: linux, wget

I wanted to download selected files from this site:

```
ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP042/SRP042286
```

If I wanted to download all of them I could do:

```
$wget -r ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP042/SRP042286/*
```

But my questions what a simple way to download just selected samples such as `SRR1299458/ - SRR1299466/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wget -r ftp://example.com/path/{dir1,dir2}`:

```
wget -r ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByStudy/sra/SRP/SRP042/SRP042286/{SRR1299458,SRR1299466}
```